# Export into different file format

Tags: apache-flex

I want to Export in charts & datagrid data into different file formats - "PDF, Word and
Excel" in my web application..I am using Flex 3 and want to export the file in local system.
Any help will be highly appreciable...
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [AlivePDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/) to create PDF files in AS3.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java/.NET/PHP or any back-end, you should be using PDF/word generation API to stream the file in required format.

For ex: You can use Apache POI or APache FOP apis to render MSword or PDF files and using Flex, users can download the files.

http://poi.apache.org/
xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/